# sources.list LMDE review

Tags: linux, debian, linux-mint, package-management

I want to create a sources.list which uses one fast mirror.
So I run netselect-apt. There comes in my first question: Does netselect-apt use ping or traffic-speed?
I trust that result and for example the fastest server seems to be "[mirror.de.leaseweb.net/debian/](http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net/debian/)"

Now I would edit my sources.list. And I got it like that:

```
deb http://linux-mint.froonix.org/ debian main upstream import deb
http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main contrib non-free
```

So does that make sense? And can I set my fast mirror for the security updates? Or could I use the mint server for everything? One server for all? But I found out the leaseweb server is a PUSH-secondary server. As I guess, that means it's always up-to-date. But the mint server won't be always up to date? Or is it a push server? And what means "Comment: DFN"?

Comment: Woah! That's quite a few questions there. What is your _basic_ question?

Comment: I would appreciate an answer on all my questions. But my main request is to explain how my sources.list should look like.